# Select hrefs that do not begin with specific pattern

Tags: css

I know I can use css to select links that begin with a specific pattern, e.g.

```
a[href^="tutorials_"] { text-color: red; }
```

Is there a way to select links that do not begin with a specific pattern, i.e. all links that do not begin with "/tutorials_".  I know there's a not selector, but I can't figure out how to use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this:

```css
a:not([href^="tutorials_"]) { 
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<a href="tutorials_1">Link 1</a>
<a href="not_tutorials_1">Not link 1</a>
<a href="not_tutorials_1">Not link 1</a>
```

Good references here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/

Comment: That works. Thank you. I was confused about where to place the not.